# Get domain from any php string

Tags: php

I am trying to get domain from inputting a url, or the domain itself (i.e "domain.com")

I tried using

```
function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

But that fails when inputting simply "domain.com"

I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: return $regs['domain'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you ask parse_url with 'domain.com' it return it as file name

```
 $pieces = parse_url($url); // 'path' => domain.com
```

**Update**

You can use such regex to take domain

```
^(https{0,1}:\/\/|)([^\/]+)(\/*.+|)$
```

it takes example.com from all lines below

```
http://example.com/dd.dfgjhdfg
https://example.com/dd.dfgjhdfg
http://example.com/
http://example.com
example.com/
example.com
```

Comment: Yes, with one item - path

Comment: I tried this $domain = $_POST['domain'];
$domainx = parse_url($domain);
$domain = $domainx['path'];

but www.john.com displays www.john.com and not john.com

Comment: He has to deal with completed url `http://examle.com/path` when you give `abc.def ` it thinks that its path only

Comment: basically I want someone to type their domain in any way lets say copy and pasting a url, or typing www.domain.com I want to get domain.com out of it everytime is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
$domainparse = parse_url($domainpost);    
$domainpath = $domainparse['path']; 

if ($domainpost == $domainpath) {
   $domain = $domainpost;
}else {
   $domain = get_domain($domainpost);
}    
$domain = str_replace("www.", "", $domain);
```

Thank you splash58! I would have used your code if I had seen it in time